# Not able to install Android studio IDE in Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: android-studio

Not able to install Android studio IDE in Ubuntu 18.04.1 from ubuntu app store.
After installation it take some time then aborted.

Comment: try this one https://androidwave.com/install-android-studio-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it from snap, not from Ubuntu Application Store.

If you don't have snap installed, first install it:

```
sudo apt install snap
```

Then install android-studio:

```
sudo snap install android-studio
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I tried **snap store** and **terminal** but the fix for me was the following.

1. Install snap by this terminal command

```
sudo apt install snapd snapd-xdg-open
```

2. then, install **android studio** by this command

```
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

If **Android Studio** is not showing in **Apps Menu**, **log out** then **log in**.

I hope this fix your problem!